# Optimizing queries with acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, query-optimization, acts-as-taggable-on

Using Rails 3.1 and `gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'` version 2.1.1.

I have a class:

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :foods
  ...
end
```

I have several different scopes on Meal that I use on a dashboard-type page. In the controller, I call, for example:

```
def index
  @today = Meal.from_today
  @yesterday = Meal.from_yesterday
end
```

I iterate over `@today` and `@yesterday` separately on the dashboard page.

I'd like to optimize the database calls. Right now, I call `<%= meal.food_list %>` in the view while iterating over each meal in both `@today` and `@yesterday`. For each meal, it queries the database to find the foods.

I've been trying to chain the queries in the controller with something like:

`@today = Meal.from_today.includes(:foods)`

but that doesn't work. Given this situation, how should I optimize the queries? Am I misusing `acts-as-taggable-on`?

Comment: `@today = Meal.includes(:foods).from_today` works, but the tag queries run again when I iterate over the items in `@today`.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, Clay. I'll report back if I find any answers.