# optimize the query using acts-as-taggable-on rubygem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, acts-as-taggable-on, taglist

I am using acts-as-taggable-on gem on my project. However, it takes about 80s to load all the tags.

I have added eager loading in the run_controller, but it is not working.
Here is the piece of code:

```
def index
  @runs = Measurement.includes(:tags).order( "run_name DESC" ).group( :run_name )#.descending #.order_by( :run => 'desc' )
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json  { render :json => @runs }
  end
end
```

I am using tag_list, which is supported by acts-as-taggable-on, to display tags. So using eager loading on Measurements has no impact on the performance. The following two are the related issues in stackflow:
1.
[acts_as_taggable_on: how to optimize the query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777069/acts-as-taggable-on-how-to-optimize-the-query)
2.
[Optimizing queries with acts_as_taggable_on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478651/optimizing-queries-with-acts-as-taggable-on?rq=1)

I looked at the log file and found that the most time-costing part is loading the tags, like

ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (69.9ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 223866 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Measurement' AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)

ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (70.2ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 223854 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Measurement' AND (taggings.context = 'tags'

It got thousands of queries to load the tag and each query cost about 0.07s.
Those following codes are using for displaying tags.

```
= form_for (run), :remote => true, :method => :put,  :html => { :class => "myform"} do |f|
  =f.text_field :tag_list, :class => "tags"
```

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I just came across this today. You can eager load through the `tags` association, as long as you don't use the `tag_list` method.

Mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777069/acts-as-taggable-on-how-to-optimize-the-query) and [here](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/91)

Answer (score 0):

Have considered switching to https://github.com/tmiyamon/acts-as-taggable-array-on . You will need to be using postgres as your database.

Take a look at this http://adamnengland.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/benchmarks-acts-as-taggable-on-vs-postgresql-arrays